# Visual Studio 2015 crashes when opening any solution

Tags: visual-studio

I have seen many solutions here about visual studio crashing. None of them have fixed my problem. In my case Visual Studio crashes when opening any type of solution, located on any drive based on any language (including opening it from Unity).

I tried deleting .suo files and it did not work. I tried installing updates and it did not work. I tried repairing and it did not work.

Is there any possible solution that can help me with this?

Comment: Does VS open correctly without loading a solution? Does creating a new solution crash VS, and if not, what about then closing and reloading that solution? Do you have any VS plugins installed and if so, have you tried disabling or uninstalling them?

Comment: No plugins installed. Loads ok when opened without a project.  Will try creating a new one when i get home

Comment: @Pedro Creating a new project also crashes Visual Studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason deleting component model cache did not help. But deleting component model cache for a previous version of visual studio (12.0) did in fact help. For some reason that was the culprit that created the problems